# How to run a function or a piece of code at compile time in C#

Tags: c#, build, compilation

I want to know is it possible to run a function or a piece of code in c# at compile time.
i want to copy a file from one location to another at compile time and not at run-time .

is it possible ?

Comment: You want to run code before the code is run? Just think about that

Comment: you can create custom build steps, or use batch scripts in your project - but fundamentally, this is MSBuild functionality, not C#. But yes, it can be done.

Comment: @FlorianF. That is no where close to the question being asked.

Comment: @DavidPilkington yes sir , i am wonder that if its possible to compile and run a simple piece of code before all

Comment: You can use [Post/Pre Build Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx) for that purpose

Comment: @FlorianF. no sir its not duplicate , the link that you send me has explanation about dynamically execution of code that happen after compilation , i am talking about separate compilation of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is perposed by Ivan in comment

[Pre/post build script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx)

we can run exe , bat with the help of these arguments .so we can run a pre compiled code before compilation of all code